# CollectionView IsGrouped property Xamarin.Forms >4.0

Tags: xamarin.forms

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping), the property IsGrouped is available on the new(ish) XF CollectionView class (only on iOS for now as the docs state)

I'm however getting a compiler error with this code:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" IsGrouped="true">
     <!--<..../>-->
</CollectionView>
```

*No property, bindable property, or event found for 'IsGrouped', or mismatching type between value and property.*

Both Android and iOS, seems the IsGrouped property may not be in the API yet, I guess.

Tried on Xamarin Forms 4.1.0.581479/673156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update your Xamarin.Forms version to **v4.2**

From the [latest release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.2/4.2.0?WT.mc_id=forms420-xamarinblog-jamont) regarding **v4.2.0.709249 (4.2.0)**

> "CollectionView Grouping iOS" ([#6590](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/6590))

Answer (score 1):

The grouping functionality is in development right now. I think the implementation for [iOS is merged](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/6590) and the Android one is [about to be merged](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/6590).

Funny that the property is already mentioned in the Docs already. Sorry about that. The grouping for iOS seems to be also merged into 4.2 that was [released yesterday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.2/4.2.0). For Android it should be there soon so don't expect it to work there for now.